# Paging in Google doc feed

Tags: paging, google-docs-api

Hi I am using google doc list api version 3.0. I am trying to get the list of documents in chunks of 20 document i.e paging with 20 records. But I do not find a way to do this. Is there any way to do this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `max-results` to limit the number of results to retrieve for each request:

https://developers.google.com/google-apps/documents-list/#getting_a_list_of_documents_and_files

Comment: I found the way to do it... There is a field "NextChunk" in DocumentsFeed which contains the link to be get the next set of data. Next time we just have to query the same link and we get the next set of data.